# Remove all non-numeric characters in a file name

Tags: macos, rename, batch-rename

I have a large number of files that are named in the format: ABC_XYZ_123.jpg.

I want to rename them in bulk so that I can get the format: 123.jpg.

How can I do this on a Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they all in a single directory, or is there a hierarchy? Could there be `ABC_123.jpg` and also `DEF_123.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` in terminal:

```
find . -type f -name "*_*_*.jpg" -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0##*_}"' {} \;
```

Would result in:

```
ABC_XYZ_123.jpg -> 123.jpg
```

Comment: So I am trying to understand what mv "$0" "${0##*_}" does. Could you please explain this to me? I would like to be able to reuse this to rename other name formats. Thanks!

Comment: It's called [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), and basically what happens is that the variable `$0` becomes the name of the file that matches the pattern `*_*_*`. When used in the curly braces `${ }` it works like an on-the-fly means of string manipulation.  `##*` signifies to match the longest pattern until it encounters `_`, which gets deleted. I realize it sounds quite complicated, although once you use it a few times it makes more sense; the page linked has some very helpful examples so try them out!

Comment: Thank you. That made sense. I was trying to manipulate the code, but couldn't get it to work. So, basically, I have a pattern 123-ABC-DEF-GHI.jpg. And, again, I want 123.jpg. How would I delete everything after the first hyphen? So it's like doing it the other way round. Thank you!

Comment: Ahh okay. I will try that. I was trying to play around with ## the whole time and that didn't do it.

Comment: Just tried this: `find . -type f -name “*-*-*.jpg" -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" “${0%%*-}”’ {} \;`Didn't work

Comment: Still no... `find . -type f -name “*-*-*.jpg" -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" “${0%%-*}”’ {} \;`

Comment: Do a dry run with the command using `echo` instead of `mv`  (eg. `find . -type f -name "*-*-*.jpg" -execdir bash -c 'echo "$0" "${0%%-*}.jpg"' {} \;` ... what is the result? It looks like your quotes are turned into fancy quotes `“”`, which definitely won't work...

Comment: Yeah it's your quotes... they need to be fixed. should be `""` not `“”`

Comment: You're welcome! Check out the link in my first comment above too, it will really help you understand how it works; it seems complex — yet quite simple when you get what it's actually doing... Cheers! :)

Comment: @ABZ: BTW, I just now realized your title said "remove all non-numeric" values, but this method removes the values based on position. If you still need a method for non-numeric specifically let me know and I'll come up with something for you.

Comment: Yes, I assumed removing non-numeric characters would be simpler. But this worked too since all the files had the same naming format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because I can never remember the command lines of the stools that specialize on this kind of stuff (like `rename`) I create a `bash` script that does the task:

```
$ ls > x.sh
$ vi x. sh
```

Within `VI`:

```
:%s/^[a-z_]*\(.*\)$/mv \0 \1/`
```

and then:

```
$ source x.sh
```

`rename` can do the likes, but, as I said, I've never bothered to learn it.

```
$ brew install rename
```